# Warning thrown because mscorlib referenced twice by assembly MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, assemblies, projects-and-solutions, mscorlib

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5):     
warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the 
same dependent assembly 
Foo.Tests -> C:\Foo.Tests\bin\Debug\Foo.Tests.dll
```

I used this little tool [ASMSPY](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/asmspy-little-tool-to-help-fix-assembly.html) and found out that 3 or 4 of my assemblies all reference `mscorlib` twice for version `2.0.0.0` and version `4.0.0.0.`

I did a full search of all files in my entire solution and found no references to mscorlib.  I can't find it in the references folder within visual studio either

This has either cropped up because I've updated the solution from VS2010 to VS2012 or updated the version of ASP.NET to the latest RTM release.  I did  both at the same time and the warnings has started appearing since.

I've read a few similar questions on SO but haven't found one that's worked for me yet.

Can anyone explain what's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: The Referenced Assemblies treeview always hides mscorlib for C# projects since it is implied that it will be there. Can you fix up the .proj file with a text editor?

Comment: That's the weird thing, there's no reference to mscorlib in the .proj file.  I've done a find in files on all files within the solution for `mscorlib` and it doesn't show up anywhere.  I know this works because I've run the search before and got hits back on other things within project files.